# Regrouping rows containing the same column content

Tags: google-sheets

I have a file containing multiple rows and columns (Name, Avatar, Company). I'd like the rows having similar content in the company column to be regrouped in my file. Here is a visual example of what i have :

```
Name     |Avatar      |Company
-------------------------------
ZZZ      |MMM         |MMM
XXX      |PPP         |AAA
UUU      |QQQ         |MMM
YYY      |OOO         |AAA
```

And what i'd like to do :

```
Name     |Avatar      |Company
-------------------------------
XXX      |PPP         |AAA
YYY      |OOO         |AAA

Name     |Avatar      |Company
-------------------------------
ZZZ      |MMM         |MMM
UUU      |QQQ         |MMM
```

How can i achieve this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
={QUERY(A2:C6,"where C='AAA'",1);
QUERY(A2:C6,"where C='MMM'",1)}
```

[image]

**OR you can take advantage of the `skipping` clause**

```
={QUERY(A2:C6,"skipping 2");
QUERY({A2:C2;A2:C6},"skipping 2")}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)